# Prove that odd perfect square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can we prove that every odd perfect square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$?

Comment: try some and see what happens.

Answer (score 41):

Observe:

$({\pm 1})^2 \equiv ({\pm 3})^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8 $

Comment: This is the simplest and best solution presented.

Comment: For those who can't quickly prove this on their own, this answer might be the least understandable.

Comment: What Todd means is that a little explanation would go a long way here.  Is this even a real proof, or just proof by example?

Comment: I've been looking at this for about 20 minutes now and trying to figure out how it constitutes a proof, and it must be really good and elegant for it to get the votes it's gotten, but I can't figure it out at all. It seems to be simply saying the first two odd perfect squares are congruent to $1($mod$ 8)$. That's clearly not a complete proof. What am I missing? More to the point, since I proved this in my head right after reading the question, and I still don't understand this answer, I wonder if the OP will understand this after not being able to prove it another way.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, all odd numbers are one of $1, -1, 3, -3 \pmod 8.$ Put another way, all odd numbers are $1,3,5,7 \pmod 8,$ as in fact all number are among $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \pmod 8.$

Comment: @ToddWilcox, built into this are observations about ring homomorphisms, such as : if $a \equiv b \pmod m,$ then  $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod m.$

Comment: Oh, cool. I'm glad I asked, and thanks, Will, for clarifying. Upvotes all around!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. :)

Todd, I apologize if it was not clear. I meant it as a hint. When I posted the answer, two other answers had already outlined an algebraic way of doing it. I think modular arithmetic is really cool for proving questions like this. So I wanted to give a different perspective.

Comment: This answer is more cryptic than Fermat's assertion that he possessed a proof of his last theorem. A line or two of explanation would go a long way. As it is written, it is almost useless.

Answer (score 38):

An odd perfect square is of the form $(2k+1)^2$.
$$(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=4(k^2+k)+1$$
Since $k^2+k=k(k+1)$ is always even, $4(k^2+k)$ is always divisible by $8$. Now it follows that every odd square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

In general, for any integers $m,n$ such that $m$ is odd and $n>2$, $m^{2^{n-2}}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $2^n$. This follows directly from the fact that $U(\mathbb{Z} /2^n\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-2}} $.

Answer (score 17):

Since the square of even and odd integers are even and odd respectively, an odd square must be of the form $(4k\pm 1)^2=16k^2\pm 8k+1=8(2k^2\pm k)+1$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: If odd squares were $3 \pmod 8,$ would that really be so bad?

Answer (score 15):

If $n^2$ is odd, then $n$ must be odd, hence $n=2k+1$. Now, $(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=4k(k+1)+1$. Since $k$ and $k+1$ are consecutive integers, one of them must be even (that is, it has a factor of $2$), thus $4k(k+1)\equiv0\pmod{8}$. Now it is clear that $n^2\equiv1\pmod{8}$ for all odd integers $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, I am trying to use 3 instead of 2.

An odd perfect square is of the form
$(6k\pm 1)^2$ or$(6k+3)^2$
$= 36k^2\pm 12k+1$ or
$36k^2+36k+9$.

$36k^2\pm 12k+1
= 12k(3k\pm 1)+1
$.
If $k$ is even,
$8 | 12k$;
if $k$ is odd,
$3k\pm 1$ is even,
so $8 | 12(3k\pm 1)$.

$36k^2+36k+9
= 36k(k+1)+9
$ and $8 | 36k(k+1)+8$
since $k(k+1)$ is even.

Not as simple, but it works.

Probably can be made to work for any odd prime $p$
by looking at
$(2pk\pm 1,3,5,...,p)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first n integers is n(n+1)/2. The product of any two consecutive integers is always even.

Every odd number can be written as the sum of two consecutive integers or (n-1)/2 + (n+1)/2.

The product of these two consecutive numbers is divisible by 2 (which is also the sum of the first (n-1)/2 integers). Therefore, (n<sup>2</sup>-1)/8 is an integer.

Thus, every odd perfect square is congruent to 1 modulo 8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the group
$$(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times = \{[1], [3], [5], [7]\} $$
under multiplication mod 8. Then
$$[1]^2 =[3]^2 = [5]^2 = [7]^2 \equiv 1 \, \,\mathrm{ mod } \, 8.$$
Since every odd integer is in exactly one of these congruence classes, every odd integer squared is 1 mod 8.